# I can not recover the values ​of my checkbox in my controller

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox

I'm working on a symfony project, I created a checkbox in twig, I want to get checked values ​​in my Controller but I still get a null, I do not know what the problem is please help:

My Action:

```
public function sendSmsAction(Request $request) {
    if ($request->isMethod('get')) {
        $ids = $request->query->get('id');
        var_dump($ids);
        die();
    }

    return $this->render('CeUtilisateurBundle:Utilisateur:sms.html.twig') 
}
```

My Form in twig:

```
<form 
    method="GET" 
    action="{{path('ce_utilisateur_send_sms') }}" 
    id="lbad_form_sms" 
    name="users"
>
    {% if listUsers is not empty %}
        {% for usr in listUsers %}

            <input 
                id="userchecked" 
                name="{{usr.id}}" 
                type="checkbox" 
                value="{{ usr.telephone }}"
            />

            <span>{{ usr.username }}</span>
</form>
```

Comment: instead of `name="{{usr.id}}"` you probably mean `name="id[{{usr.id}}]"` ? or something else, because the `name` attribute should start with a character, not with a number (I assume it's a number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're missing closing tags in twig for your `if` and `for`, but I assume they just got lost during copying.

Second, you give all your input elements the same id "userchecked". Each HTML element should have a unique ID, e.g. by appending your user ID.

Something similar happens with the name attribute. If you give multiple form elements the same name, only the last one will be submitted.

So your form should look something like this:

```
<form 
    method="GET" 
    action="{{path('ce_utilisateur_send_sms') }}" 
    id="lbad_form_sms" 
    name="users"
>
    {% if listUsers is not empty %}
        {% for usr in listUsers %}
            <input 
                id="{{"userchecked_" ~ usr.id}}"
                name="{{"checked_" ~ usr.id}}"
                type="checkbox" 
                value="{{ usr.telephone }}"
            />

            <span>{{ usr.username }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer un sms!"/>
</form>
```

To fix your controller, you have to get the input by the name field. Since it is dynamically created, it's easiest to just get all parameters and loop over them.

```
public function sendSmsAction(Request $request) {
    if ($request->isMethod('get')) {
        $parameters = $request->query->all();
        foreach ($parameters as $name => $value) {
            var_dump("$name: $value");
        }
        die();
    }

    return $this->render('CeUtilisateurBundle:Utilisateur:sms.html.twig') 
}
```

Note that there will be no submitted parameter for an empty checkbox.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I just made the changes in my files but it does not work yet, I copied your code but it always returns a null, I added that to submit my form at the end                                           
 <a  href="{{ path('ce_utilisateur_send_sms') }}" class="btn btn-primary lbad_btngc">Envoyer un sms</a>

Comment: If you want the form to auto-submit, you need to use either a `button` or `input` of type `submit`. I edited my answer to include an input to submit your form.

Comment: Great! If your problem is solved, consider accepting the answer which helped most in solving the problem.

Comment: how to do that please ?

Comment: There should be a grey check mark next to each answer like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png). If you click it, it will turn green and mark the answer as accepted. Accepting an answer is not final and you can change it anytime. For more information on accepting answers, you can refer to the official [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or [this excellent answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 1):

Aside from other issues in your example, in order to get those values you need to change the HTML part that displays checkboxes and give them different IDs, proper values and the same name:

```
<input id="telephone{{ usr.id }}" name="telephone[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ usr.telephone }}"/>
```

Notice that the `name` property is the same for every checkbox and has `[]` at the end - this allows to pass multiple values for one property.

Next to that I would suggest to use a POST request to submit the form, instead of the GET you are using. If you do so, you can get the selected phone numbers in the controller like that:

```php
$telephones = $request->request->get('telephone');
```

If you want to submit the form with a GET request, then use `query` instead of the `request`:

```php
$telephones = $request->query->get('telephone');
```